# Dividing an array of numbers with another array of numbers in Processing

Tags: arrays, processing

I am a beginner to coding and trying to make simple data visualizations using processing. In order to test, i created a csv file where three columns of data are listed where the 2nd and third are numbers. I parsed the columns and tried dividing the 2nd column of numbers with the 3rd. But unfortunately the results are showing zero.

the code is

String tag = "dataset.csv";
String [] rawData;

int [] marks = new int[6];
int [] maxMarks = new int[6];

float [] percentage = new float[6];

void **setup**() {
  size(800, 800);
  smooth();

rawData = loadStrings(tag);

for (int i = 1; i<rawData.length; i++) {
    String [] thisRow = split(rawData[i], ",");

String subject = thisRow[0];       //// name of the subject
    marks[i-1] = int(thisRow[1]);       //// marks recieved
    maxMarks [i-1] = int(thisRow[2]);         //// maximum marks
    percentage [i-1]    = (marks[i-1]/maxMarks[i-1]);
  }
  println(marks);       //// prints the numbers 80,45,40,25,30,40
  println(maxMarks);    //// prints the numbers 100,50,50,50,50,50
  println(percentage);  //// prints 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
}

void **draw**() {
}

I wanted the percentage to be calculated and displayed. :(

It would be a great help if someone can help me to sort this out. 
Many thanks in advance!

Cheers, 
Yousuf

Comment: you are getting 0 as result. there are many situations where this can occur.what is the data type of marks[i-1] and maxMarks[i-1]. is it going out of data type range? check  out the possible cases.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using c++ ?

haha , you need to know , **an integer divide integer , the result must be an integer !**

you want to get a percent , that is a float value .

so just **cast** it !

`static_cast<float>(int_value )` *[ C++ style ]*

or

`float(int_value)` *[c style]* is both ok ~

so , just change here :

```
percentage [i-1]    = (marks[i-1]/maxMarks[i-1]);
```

to

```
percentage [i-1]    = (float(marks[i-1])/maxMarks[i-1]) * 100 ;

or

percentage [i-1]    = (static_cast<float>(marks[i-1])/maxMarks[i-1]) * 100;
```

`*100` , because you want a percent value

Comment: Thank you so much 小文件! 
Such a simple one :) 

I am using Processing which works based on Java.
I just turned the integers into float, and now it works